# Выбор модели данных для часто меняющихся требований по форматам

Tags: sql, база-данных, nosql

Задача состоит в том, чтобы формировать пользовательские данные в *XML* виде. XSD схема для этих файлов часто меняется, заказчик выпускает новые форматы (меняются типы, иерархия и т.д.)

Какую модель бд лучше использовать в данном случае: классическую *реляционную*, или *документарную* (**NoSQL**)?

Comment: Не совсем понятно как связаны форматы XML для вывоа и формат хранения данных. Слишком общий вопрос и уходит больше в теорию. Добавьте, пожалуйста практических подробностей. Что за данные? Что значит "меняется схема XML файлов"? Желательно с примером: было-стало

Comment: Цель проекта - получение XML файла (с пользовательскими данными), который соответствует определенной XSD схеме.

На данный момент я строю по данной XSD собственные таблицы в реляционной базе данных.

Мне кажется можно ускорить процесс создания новых таблиц, их изменения, тем, что использовать NoSQL подход.

Comment: _"классическую реляционную, или документарную (NoSQL)?"_ -- можно хранить как есть. например, в sql server для этого есть специальный тип данных [xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh403385(v=sql.120).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем ответ, скорее размышления. У нас сейчас аналогичная задача.
Приходят на обработку финансовые документы в виде XML, форматов много, периодически выходят новые версии. Хранить как-то надо.
У нас Oracle+Java, так что выбора в пользу No SQL особо не было:)
На пути к сохранению идёт два преобразования:

XML -> Java объект(JaxB) -> Java объект в нашем внутреннем формате, который ложится в РСУБД.

Есть некоторый абстрактный класс А, который содержит в себе общие поля для всех документов(дата, инициатор, счета и прочее)

Для разных типов документов создаются наследники А (В1 В2 В3), и для их хранения создаются таблицы, которые содержат поля из А и дополнительно поля из В1 В2 В3.

Средствами наследования различаем типы документов.
В чем плюс? Можно строить составные индексы по полям как из класса А так и из В.

Различия версий одного типа документа (если появляются новые поля итп) дополняются хвостами (ссылки из B на объекты классов B11 B12 B13), которые имеют связь с В1 один к одному в случае с таблицами.

Т.е. для новой версии мы не меняем структуру данных, а добавляем новые сущности, при том что бОльшая часть алгоритмов продолжает успешно работать с любыми версиями без изменений.

У нас всё несколько строго ещё и из-за того, что Java объекты хранятся в IMDG(хранение ВСЕХ данных в оперативной памяти грида), и в будущем планируется отказ от Oracle как от персистентного хранилища в пользу No SQL. 
Т.е. РСУБД уйдёт, а структура хранения Java-объектов в IMDG останется.

Я говорил не столько о выборе между РСУБД и No SQL, а о борьбе с меняющимися форматами данных и их хранении.
Надеюсь сказал что-то полезное.:)

Comment: Да, полезно, есть над чем подумать. Спасибо.